# looking for an easy way to look up possible values for Dublin Core Metadata Element Set etc

Tags: epub

I'm looking for an easy way to look up possible values for Dublin Core Metadata Element Set elements and so on.
For example, a metadata element (sorry if my terminology is wrong here) might be:

```
<dc:language>en-US</dc:language>
```

.  How do I find out if, for example, an accepted alternative value here is en-AU or something else, i.e.:

```
<dc:language>en-AU</dc:language>
```

I've looked here: http://wiki.dublincore.org/index.php/User_Guide/Publishing_Metadata#dc:language ( and here http://www.idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-publications.html).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sigil](https://github.com/Sigil-Ebook/Sigil/releases/tag/0.9.6) (freeware) will automatically insert the proper metadata entries for epub3 (and epub2) books.

(You'll have to delete the default **dc:language en** entry. 
Then click Add Metadata, OK and select the language.)

AFAIK, it supports all metadata entries listed in the epub3 and epub2 specs.